# EasyJet cancelled flight alternative over UK without visa

Tags: visas, cancellations, compensation

I bought a direct easyJet flight from Palermo to Amsterdam. Due to the airport worker strike my flight was cancelled. There were 2 alternative flights both were with one stop. However, EasyJet alternative flights screen doesn't show the middle stop airport without clicking details. I checked the first alternative's itinerary and saw that it is over Naples. But then I selected the other alternative since it was 1 hour later (but without checking the itinerary). Then in the flight change email I realized that it is over Bristol airport. I have EU residency but no UK visa. I directly reached out EasyJet to revert my alternative selection but they said that it is not possible. So I lost my ticket with single click in the last day of my vacation. Is it possible for me to get any compansation?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but are you sure you can't take this flight? You can transit the UK without a UK visa if you have 'a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland' or 'a uniform format category D visa for entry to a country in the EEA or Switzerland', and your flight out of the UK leaves by midnight the day after your flight into the UK. Does this apply to you?

Comment: Hi @MJeffryes, I couldn't find an answer for that, also EasyJet didn't give any answer other than "you can't choose other alternative flight for free". So not to risk it I bought another flight over Milan.